# Google App Engine not supporting special characters like British pound

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a jsp that takes input from the user and a servlet to handle the data submitted. I am using an Ajax request to call the servlet and to pass the parameters along with it.

Here's my jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java"  import="java.util.*,com.*,bo.*" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript">


function check(){
              var i = document.getElementById('input').value;
              var escapedi = escape(i);
              escapedi = escapedi.replace("%u2019","%27");
              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhr.open("GET","LinkHandler?text="+ escapedi,true);
              xhr.send();
       }


</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="input"/><input type="button" onclick="check()" value="Submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my Servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String text = URLDecoder.decode(req.getParameter("text"),"UTF-8");
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

The code runs fine on a normal Web-Project, but when I run it on a Google Web App Project, some of the special characters like the British pound are displayed as "?".

How do I solve this? Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

It might be because App Engine's [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) is different from your local machine's Locale. You can print the current local of the environment using

```
Locale.getDefault()
```

Also, you can change it using setDefault()

Comment: the above statement gives en_IN in both environments, not sure though how it affects the code.

Comment: Got it!

Do not escape the "i" as shown in the code above. instead directly pass the variable and decode as UTF-8 on Servlet side.